# trying to open .deb files in raspbian

Tags: raspbian

I was just trying to get steam working on a raspberry pi 4 and I went to the install page and it gave me a .deb file. I am a Linux noob so that could stand for "Decent Enough Broadband". when I tried to do a simple double click on it, asked me if I wanted to install it, I replied "install". it then loaded cache for a while, asked for my password, loaded some more cache, said it was running then says "failed to install file. one of the selected packages failed to install correctly. More information is available in the detailed report." I cant find that "detailed report" anywhere. its probably something I have missed and is really obvious. please help.

thanks in advance, Tom

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/deb || Is the package compatible for RPi? || use `sudo dpkg -i debfile` to install

Comment: Is it for arm or amd?

Comment: @SohanArafat its ARM

Comment: As suggested by *Swedgin* you have tried to install the package with `sudo dpkg -i debfile` on the commandline. Please [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/114315/edit) your question and add the complete output of this command to it. Also add the link to the deb package you have got.

Comment: I have this problem too. Many people have issues asking where to find the “detailed report”. No one ever answers this question. “WHAT DETAILED REPORT?” Those trying to help start asking a bunch of other questions. I must conclude that the “detailed report” message is in error and that this is a bug in the raspberry pi package installer. These messages go back at least five years. Can someone confirm that there is no detailed report? And suggest another way to try to install a .deb package that will at least say why it fails?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Raspberry Pi StackExchange!

.deb files are software package format files. Installing a package from the .deb file is the same as using package managers like apt or apt-get. But installing .deb files is much more complicated.

.deb files are installed by the command `sudo dpkg -i NameOfFile.deb`

Here, `dpkg` is another built-in package manager, but it's not that user friendly. And .deb files are installed using it.

You'll find detailed log/information by using this method.

Answer (score 1):

As the comment goes I think you are trying to install a .deb file that has dependencies out of the source. And also you have to run `dpkg` with `sudo`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the .deb file is ARM64 and not AMD64. AMD64 is compiled for the x86 series of processors.